# dynamic path in java application

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I want to specify the path dynamically. myapp/CopyFolder and myapp/RunFolder's are inside application like myapp/WEB-INF. The code I have given below is in .java file(in eclipse) and in .class file(in tomcat inside `myapp/WEB-INF/classname/packagename/`). My deployment is in tomcat.

```
 try {
        functionNamesObject.Integration(
                ".txt",
                path+"\\CopyFolder",
                path+"\\RunFolder",
                "app.exe",
                "Input.txt"
        );
```

I want path to be dynamic when I call above function. I tried with `getResource("MyClass.class")` ,`new File("").getAbsolutePath();` and `System.getProperty("user.dir")` but no use. Is there any other way?

Comment: I answered this in another one of your questions. `CopyFolder` won't exist by default on an installation. You will need to create it manually. As such you will know where you create it, so hard code it into your app.

Comment: do you want to know the deployment directory (`webapps/application`) or the `WEB-INF` folder of your deployed app?

Comment: @Katona I want to know deployment directory (`webapps/application`)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes I have to create CopyFolder and RunFolder then I will place the files I want to use there.

Comment: @niren I think you can get it with `getServletContext.getRealPath("")` in your servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `path` value as below:

```
URL resource = getClass().getResource("/");
String path = resource.getPath();
```

This will return the absolute path to to your `myApp/WEB-INF/classes` directory.